# jQuery run function when get has finished

Tags: jquery, html, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I am trying to animate page transitions in my app with jQuery. Every time I `$.get()` a new section (from HTML file) to my page, I'm trying to animate it scrolling into place. This is my script so far:

```
function loadMain(){
    $("#homeSection").remove();
    $("#blogSection").remove();
    $.get('main.html', function(data){ 
        $('#navbar').after(data); 
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#homeSection").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

My problem is that the animation isn't loading. Please note that the `$.get()` request should re-insert the `#homeSection`, and eventually it shows up in the DOM. Also I get this in FF's console:

> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

And it points to the `scrollTop:` line in my script.

I'm pretty certain that this relates to the fact that I'm trying to scroll something that isn't there *yet*, but I'm not sure on how to block `$.get()`'s asynchronous call in order to animate only when it's present. I've been reading on `[deferred][1]` and `[promise][2]` but the concepts are eluding me. Can anyone point me out my mistakes and help out?

Comment: You do realize `$('#navbar').after(data);` runs when the get is complete, right? Why didn't you put the rest of what you want to run when the get is complete up there? *"I'm not sure on how to block $.get()'s asynchronous call"* you don't need/want to do that.

Comment: is the above script executed after the dom has finished loading?

Comment: @Lal yes: `$().ready(function(){loadMain();});`

Comment: `$("#homeSection")` certainly isn't there when `$("#homeSection").offset().top` runs. It was removed.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 please read the whole question.

Comment: The get() call make take some time to get its results -- while it's waiting the rest of the code executes. If you want it to execute after the get has returned you need to put the code in get's callback.

Comment: I'm just confirming your "I'm pretty certain ..." statement.

Comment: Indeed, placing the animation bit inside the callback did the trick. Thank you all for pointing that out.

Comment: @KevinB want to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the animation into the success callback as well so that it will also run after the get is complete.

```
function loadMain(){
    $("#homeSection").remove();
    $("#blogSection").remove();
    $.get('main.html', function(data){ 
        $('#navbar').after(data); 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#homeSection").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```